# SQL query returns multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wrote a SQL query to return a values from column if product type of one contract more than 1.

When I use this query to my main query I get this error:

> Single row subquery returns more than one row

When I use `rownum = 1`, then no rows are returned.

I need to return the type of the contract

```
(SELECT
     MAX(TYPE) AS TYPE,
     CONT_NO
 FROM 
     (SELECT    
          MO.CONT_NO, 
          MO.TYPE, 
          COUNT (*) C1
      FROM 
          TABLE1.MORG MO 
      GROUP BY    
          MO.CONT_NO, MO.TYPE) DRT1  
 WHERE  
     DRT1.CONT_NO = CONT_NO 
 GROUP BY 
     CONT_NO
 HAVING 
     COUNT (*) = 1 AND SUM (C1) > 1
)
```

Comment: What is your question? The error: "Single row subquery returns more than one row" is self explanatory

Comment: Can you please give your full query here.

Answer (score 0):

There may be several methods to solve your problem, but you do not reveal much detail.

**IF** you are going to include that subquery in the `select clause` it most probably needs to be "correlated" to some value of the current result set. e.g.

```
SELECT 
...

      (SELECT
            MAX(TYPE) AS type
      FROM (
            SELECT
                  mo.TYPE
                , COUNT(*) c1
            FROM TABLE1.MORG mo
            WHERE mo.CONT_NO = XYZ.CONT_NO --<<<< a "correlation" to the outer query
            GROUP BY
                  mo.TYPE
            ) drt1
      WHERE drt1.CONT_NO = CONT_NO --<<<< is this a "correlation" to the outer query?
      HAVING SUM(C1) > 1)

FROM XYZ 
....
```

This is because you are NOT ALLOWED to return multiple rows in a "cell" of the selected rows, so you need to restrict the result to a SINGLE VALUE.

In SQL Server a very useful technique for substituting "correlated subqueries" is to use a OUTER APPLY (or CROSS APPLY) instead, but it appears that this subquery could (should?) be used as a joined derived table.

```
SELECT
       ...
     , x.type
FROM XYZ t
LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT
            MAX(TYPE) AS type
          , CONT_NO
      FROM (
            SELECT
                  mo.CONT_NO
                , mo.TYPE
                , COUNT(*) c1
            FROM TABLE1.MORG mo
            GROUP BY
                  mo.CONT_NO
                , mo.TYPE
      ) drt1
      WHERE drt1.CONT_NO = CONT_NO
      GROUP BY
            CONT_NO
      HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
      AND SUM(C1) > 1
) x ON t.cont_no = x.cont_no
```

Comment: what is the XYZ  table,

Comment: i have no idea.... it is a table you have, just a place in the query for you table... understand? you didn't give us much to work with

Answer (score 0):

If this is SQL Server, you might want:

```
(SELECT TOP 1 MAX(TYPE) AS TYPE,
 FROM (SELECT MO.CONT_NO, MO.TYPE, COUNT(*) C1
       FROM TABLE1.MORG MO 
       GROUP BY MO.CONT_NO, MO.TYPE
      ) DRT1  
 WHERE DRT1.CONT_NO = <external reference>.CONT_NO 
 GROUP BY CONT_NO
 HAVING COUNT (*) = 1 ANDSUM (C1) > 1
)
```

Perhaps the biggest issue is `WHERE DRT1.CONT_NO = CONT_NO`.  The `CONT_NO` refers to `DRTS.CONT_NO`.  It should probably be a correlation to the outer query.